# How can I prevent the alt-tab shortcut from nesting terminal windows?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, window

I like to have multiple terminal windows open sometimes, however when I use alt-tab it nests all instances of the same application in one icon and then you must wait a second for it to let you tab through those instances. Is there a way that I can just have it treat the multiple terminal windows like separate applications so I can switch through faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to wait around for the group to expand when alt-tabbing, you can use the grave key (`) while still holding alt  - this should be to the left of the 1 key on your keyboard. This is useful if you want to pick the window of an application that isn't currently active (e.g. you have many terminals open but are currently in Firefox)

You can also directly use alt-` without pressing tab at all, if for example a terminal window is currently active and you want to switch to a different terminal window.

Essentially, alt-tab switches between applications; alt-` switches between windows within an application.

Comment: @RyanGC If this answer solved your problem, [please accept it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/44179) :)